# How to read dates using xlrd?

Tags: python-2.7, xlrd

This is the code where "rec" variable is used to read the dates in excel sheet but its printing float value how to print that in date format for example '2015:09:02'

```
for rec in sorted(out.keys()):
print rec #printing float values
print str(out[rec])
```

I got output:

```
42240.0
24
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Excel internally stored date values as floats. So in <kbd>xlrd</kbd> if you want to read Excel date values as Python date values, you have to use the `xldate_as_tuple` method to get the date.

Documentation: http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html#xlrd.xldate_as_tuple-function

Here's a generic Example:

```
import datetime, xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook("myexcelfile.xls")
sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)
a1 = sh.cell_value(rowx=0, colx=0)
a1_as_datetime = datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(a1, book.datemode))
print 'datetime: %s' % a1_as_datetime
```

If you create the file `myexcelfile.xls` and enter a date in cell A1 and run the above code, you should be able to see the correct datetime value in the `a1_as_datetime` variable.