# Python date Time for Excel

Tags: python

How to convert following dates in excel in float values by Python.

Problem Statement: I have a dates data in which dates are entered but users and users used different cell format to enter dates.For example some used cell format as`dd-yy-yyyy` and some used `mm-dd-yyyy` in excel cell while entering the data  ( in fact user used different excel format for dates in their files).When I am trying to consolidate dates then find that dates are  in different cell formats randomly. In excel I can copy dates column and paste all in a separate column as a value only,It gives me integer value which is same regardless and format used in cell. And later applied a single format to all value and gets all my dates in same format.

But , I want to make a script in Python in which first: all different cell formats for dates are converted to float value (like i do in excel) then I will convert all dates back to standard format i.e `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Formet  Dates   format  Date in numeric value   Reformatted in excle as  dd-mm-yyyy
format 1    30-08-2018  dd-mm-yyyy  43342.51551 30-08-2018
format 2    08-30-2018  mm-dd-yyyy  43342.51551 30-08-2018

Comment: _"I want to make a script"_ - So did you make the script? Or you mean you want someone _here_ to make the script?

Comment: Do you have any way to tell if a date is DD-MM-YYYY or MM-DD-YYYY? Any indicator in the other columns in the Excel file?

Comment: 1. I don't get the question, what exactly is your problem? 2. How can you convert a date into a float if you don't know how to interpret it?

Comment: Yes rdimaio , in excel , we can see the date display format of cell , But i am looking for a way  to find it via python ,that python can tell me that the date dispaly format of cell is dd-mm-yyyy or mm-dd-yyy

Answer (score 0):

No script can tell you, if 03-05-2014 means 3rd May or 5th March. It's not God and can't do, what you're unable to do.

Only clues:

- If some value consists of four digits, it's the year.
- If one value is higher than twelve, you can say that this value must be the day (or the year)
- If there are several date values by the same user, you may presume that he or she kept consistlently one format and deduce the format from another field.

Comment: Thanks ,but converting any date format in float will tell the real date in excel, that why i asked this question

Comment: Interesting: how would Excel do that?

Comment: But I believe somewhere in Excel you set the format the date is compliant to, right?

Comment: in excel all format converts to standerd value in float for example

Comment: 30-08-2018 dd-mm-yyyy 43342.51551
08-30-2018 mm-dd-yyyy 43342.51551

Comment: Of course, but you told excel whether your 8 is the month or the day. I believe that March 5th or May 3rd will have different floating point numbers and the point is that you don't know how to tell Excel whether your 3 is the month or the day. Or am I missing somwthing?

Comment: If Excel knows the right date (as your comment suggests), i.e., the cell contains the correct time value, but only the display format is wrong, why don't you just change the display format for the entire column?

Comment: here i use two different format in excel ,that can be checked in excel by looking in format cell. and then i copied both value  and pase specila  as number only in last column, and it  gave me the same value , regardless my format selection, excel understood itself the format i used to enter date

Comment: Look at https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8E10019E-D5D8-47A1-BA95-DB95123D273E

Comment: Thanks Frank, my data is made up of many files from a different user and changing the format in excel is done but  i am looking how python will do it.

Comment: Frank , can python tell me what cell format is used in particular cell like excel do

Comment: I don't understand your problem. If it is one Excel file that you are interested in, you can simply change the display format inside Excel to the one you prefer and read the data.

However, if you get regularly Excel with all kinds of date formats, you can use the package xlrd. There is already a stackoverflow answer which perfectly describes what to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32430679/how-to-read-dates-using-xlrd
You only have to change file name and the cells.

Answer (score 0):

Before answering your question, you need to know the special term for:

> dates in excel in float values

which is actually so called [**Serial Date**](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm) in excel

#### Answer

Assuming that the frameworks you use to read excel file does not convert cell values according to their format.

The easiest way to achieve this is first manually set the format of cells with dates value to Number format to get the *serial date* value.

Then, when you read the excel file you can convert *serial date* to *datetime* object with the following method:

```
def serial_to_datetime(serial):
    """ Convert excel serial date to :class:`datetime` """
    # 30/12/1899 used instead of 01/01/1900 in order to offset 2 days due to, serial counting & excel leap year bug
    dt = datetime.fromordinal(datetime(1899, 12, 30).toordinal() + int(serial))
    h, r = divmod(serial % 1 * 24, 1)
    m, r = divmod(r * 60, 1)
    return dt.replace(hour=int(h), minute=int(m), second=int(r * 60))
```

Now, you may then convert to any format you want with [datetime.strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime)